# Ag-Grid get Group column names

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm tryin to get all id's names from Row Group after clicking on 'Pivot mode' and it gives me just the name of 'Group'.

[image]

[image]

There is any way to get the name of 'Item'?

Answer (score 0):

You can access event parameter whenever pivotMode is changed through `columnPivotModeChanged`.
And you can also able to get RowGroupColumns by calling `getRowGroupColumns()` through `columnApi` in event parameter.

1. `columnPivotModeChanged()`

```js
event: ColumnPivotModeChangedEvent 

onColumnPivotModeChanged = (
    event: ColumnPivotModeChangedEvent<TData>
) => void;

interface ColumnPivotModeChangedEvent<TData = any> {
  // The grid api. 
  api: GridApi<TData>;
  // The column api. 
  columnApi: ColumnApi;
  // Application context as set on `gridOptions.context`. 
  context: any;
  // Event identifier 
  type: string;
}
```

2. `getRowGroupColumns()`

```js
function getRowGroupColumns(): Column[];
```

**Example**

`main.js`

```js
const VueExample = {
  template: `
        <div style="height: 100%">
            <div class="example-wrapper">
                <ag-grid-vue
                style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
                class="ag-theme-alpine"
                :columnDefs="columnDefs"
                @grid-ready="onGridReady"
                @columnPivotModeChanged="columnPivotModeChanged"
                :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
                :autoGroupColumnDef="autoGroupColumnDef"
                :sideBar="sideBar"
                :rowData="rowData"></ag-grid-vue>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,
```

```js
  methods: {
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;

      const updateData = (data) => params.api.setRowData(data);

      fetch('https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/olympic-winners.json')
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => updateData(data));
    },
    columnPivotModeChanged(params: ColumnPivotModeChangedEvent){
      const rowGroupList = params.columnApi.getRowGroupColumns()

      console.log(rowGroupList.map(rowGroup => rowGroup.getColId()))
    }
  },
```

**Reference**

[Grid-event: columnPivotModeChanged](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-columns-columnPivotModeChanged)

[Column-api: getRowGroupColumns](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-api/#reference-rowGroups-getRowGroupColumns)

I hope this helps